# Having trouble extracting data from loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to extract data in a row on sheet "info" and place it into another workbook, based on what is in column "G" or sheet "Data". The data that I am trying to copy has 22 rows and 5 columns, the first row being a header. I wrote a loop to loop through the "info" sheet, but I am not getting the correct values. I believe that I am not setting up my array correctly. Thank you for any help you can afford. Here is the code:

```
  var infoSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName('info');
  var infoData = infoSheet.getRange('A2:E22').getValues();
  var newUserInfo = '';
  for (var j=0; j<infoData[0].length; ++j){
    if (location == infoData[0][j]);{
    newUserInfo = infoData[0];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is `infoData`, which will be like this:

```
[
  [ A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 ],      // infoData[0]
  [ A3, B3, C3, D3, E3 ],      // infoData[1]
   ...
  [ A22, B2, C22, D22, E22 ]   // infoData[20]
]
```

Your loop takes `j` through the elements of infoData[0], column by column, looking for a match for `location`. This looks strange. Normally, we'd expect "records" to be in rows, with a value like `location` appearing in a particular column.

If indeed `location` is in `A`, or column 0 in the array, then the loop you're looking for would be:

```
var newUserInfo = [];
for (var row=0; row<infoData.length; ++row){
  if (location == infoData[row][0]);{
    // Found matching location; get info for new user
    for (var col=1; col<infoData[row].length; ++col) {
      newUserInfo.push(infoData[row][col]);
    }
    break; // Exit after copying the matching row
  }
}
if (newUserInfo.length > 0) {
  // Now, the newUserInfo array contains the data that was
  // to the RIGHT of the location column.
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.lastRow()+1,1,1,newUserInfo.length).setValues([newUserInfo]);
}
```

EDIT: Updated code... now the search will exit once the matching row has been found and its data has been copied to `newUserData`, which is being treated as an array. After the search loop, the copied values are available to be written to your destination sheet - in this example, it's assumed that they are added as a new row at the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: I apologize for not giving more details about the project. @Mogsdad you are correct that the location is in A. I am trying to copy the data from B, C, D of the row that matches "location". Then, that data will be pasted into another worksheet.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between incrementing before the variable ++i and after it i++  ?

Comment: The way it's used here, there is no difference whether you pre or post-increment.

Comment: I am still having trouble getting the loop to extract the correct data. I rearranged the code and corrected the arrays, but it is still not producing the desired results.

Comment: Sounds like another question!

Comment: Code has been updated, demonstrating one way to grab all the data from the matching row, ready to be copied to another sheet.

Answer (score 2):

After cosulting [the doc pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()):

> getValues()
>
> Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Returns a JavaScript 2d array with all the values, indexed by row then by column. Each item of the array may be of one of the following types: Boolean, int, String or Date. Cells that are empty will be represented by an empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at 1,1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from 0,0.

This means you should write:

```
nestedLoop:
for (var j=0; j<infoData.length; j++)//increment after, index 1 === 0
{
   for (var h=0;h<infoData[j].length;h++)
   {
       if (location == infoData[j][h])
       {
           newUserInfo = infoData[j];
           break nestedLoop;//we can break out of both loops now
       }
   }
}
```

Though I'm not all too sure about the labels in the global namespace, so to be on the safe side, I'd write it like this:

```
newUserInfo = (function()
{
    for (var i=0; i<infoData.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<infoData[i].length;j++)
        {
            if (location == infoData[i][j])
            {
                return infoData[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;//nothing found...
}());
```